# Running deployServer gradle task with custom domainsplittings.xml and urlrewriterules.xml fails

Tags: intershop

After adding our custom urlrewriterules.xml and domainsplittings.xml files to our cartridge in "staticfiles\share\system\config\cluster\" folder we can no longer execute deployServer gradle task. Task fails with following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':init_project:deployShareFiles'.
> Could not deploy files of task :init_project:deployShareFiles
   > Task :init_project:deployShareFiles: Resource 'C:\Work\Project\intershop-ci\sources\projects\webshop\build\server\share\system\config\cluster\domainsplittings.xml' already defined for Task :bc_urlrewrite:deployShareFiles
   > Task :init_project:deployShareFiles: Resource 'C:\Work\Project\intershop-ci\sources\projects\webshop\build\server\share\system\config\cluster\urlrewriterules.xml' already defined for Task :bc_urlrewrite:deployShareFiles
```

Does anybody knows why is that and how can we add our own url rewrite rules without editing those files every time after deployServer (which copy system rules from bc_urlrewrite cartridge)?

Thank you for you answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at [Cookbook - Deployment Tools ICM 7.x](https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/282B92) / [23 Recipe: Replace a File Deployed by Another Component](https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/282B92#Cookbook-DeploymentToolsICM7.9-Recipe:ReplaceaFileDeployedbyAnotherComponent):

> Replacing a file is a drastic measure. Consider using content filters to alter an existing file instead of providing your own version, because it eases future migrations.

It looks like you can't use the configuration framework's environment specific files in order to overload the `$IS_SHARE/system/config/cluster/domainsplittings.xml` and `$IS_SHARE/system/config/cluster/urlrewriterules.xml` files (loaded with a fixed path, not via the configuration framework).

The error indicates that two different components (`bc_urlrewrite` vs. `init_project`) are trying to deploy the same target file. You've got two options:

- Use content filters in order to alter the existing files, see [Cookbook - Deployment Tools ICM 7.x](https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/282B92) / [15 Recipe: Change Deployed File Content With Filters](https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/282B92#Cookbook-DeploymentToolsICM7.9-Recipe:ChangeDeployedFileContentWithFilters)
- Resolve the conflict by excluding the file from the deployment of the original component `bc_urlrewrite` (provide custom deployment logic), see: [Cookbook - Deployment Tools ICM 7.x](https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/282B92) / [14 Recipe: Provide Custom Deployment Configuration and Logic](https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/282B92#Cookbook-DeploymentToolsICM7.9-Recipe:ProvideCustomDeploymentConfigurationandLogicProvideDeploymentLogic)

Comment: Thanks! It works by excluding those files from bc_urlrewrite cartridge.

Comment: I just tried that and while deployServer runs without error, every time urlrewriterules.xml and domainsplittings.xml gets copied from I don't know which location :) Definitely not from our init_project cartridge because they contain definitions for "inSPIRED-inTRONICS-Site" site. I'm still unable to deploy our custom url rewrite rules xml files...

Comment: Please try with a fresh deployment, i.e. empty out your server directory before running the `deployServer` gradle task.

Comment: Tried that, deleted all content, and from somewhere intronics urlrewriterules.xml and domainsplittings.xml gets copied to it. Problem is I can't find those files anywhere. Not in system cartridges, not in responsive store cartridges... Strange.

Comment: Both files are part of the `bc_urlrewrite` cartridge (`com.intershop.business:bc_urlrewrite`). The full paths in your artifact repository should be: `https://<artifact_repository>/<releases>/com.intershop.business/bc_urlrewrite/<version>/zips/bc_urlrewrite-share-<version>.zip!system/config/cluster/domainsplittings.xml` and `https://<artifact_repository>/<releases>/com.intershop.business/bc_urlrewrite/<version>/zips/bc_urlrewrite-share-<version>.zip!system/config/cluster/urlrewriterules.xml`. You'll find them locally in your gradle cache only (and after deployment in the server folder).

Comment: Yes, I found them in bc_urlrewrite-13.1.2.zip file in gradle cache. That's probably reason why I didn't find them with `find` :) And is there some way that I can prevent them to be copied to server folder on deploy? I tried adding deployment/deploy.gradle file with excludes but those files are still copied on serverDeploy.